# find directories and change ownership using bash

Tags: bash, syntax, gnu-findutils

I am trying to find directories older than 150 days and change their ownership as root. Please can you advice on how do i fix the below pls?

`find /mnt/mailfolder/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +150 -printf "%P\n" -exec "chown -R oracle:oinst`

`` find: missing argument to `-exec' ``

Comment: You need to add `{} \;` to the exec where `{}` refers to the found file (which is the missing arg) `-exec chown -R oracle:oinst {} \;`

Comment: thanks. It finds the folder but fails on the chown "N01
find: ‘chown -R oracle:oinstall’: No such file or directory
"

Answer (score -1):

Try using

find /home/$USER -mtime +150 -print &&
chown -R root:root /home/$USER

Comment: It messed up every folder with "oracle:oinstall" I ran what u advised ```find /mnt/mailfolder/$folder -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +150 -printf "%P\n" && chown -R oracle:oinstall /mnt/mailfolder/$folder ```

Comment: && does not look at the first half of the script and changes directory to every folder